# Persisting JSON Array into Database using JPA Repository

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jax-rs

I am learning spring boot. As a part of this learning, I am creating a invoicing application's backend using REST Webservices. Here is my JSON Request.

```
{
    "invoice": {
            "invoiceNumber":"KB123456",
            "custId":"123",
            "pricingId":"234",
            "empId":"456",
            "gstCode":"HSN1234",
            "invoiceSubTotal":"1234.00",
            "invoiceGst":"18%",
            "invoiceGstAmount":"123.45",
            "invoiceTotal":"1357.45",
        "invoiceLineItems": [
        {
            "invoiceLineNo":"KB123456-1",
            "invoiceLineDesc":"Des123",
            "invoiceQty":"2",
            "invoicePpu":"0.18",
            "invoiceGstCode":"HSN1235",
            "invoiceGstPercentage":"18%",
            "invoiceLineAmount":"123",
            "invoiceLineTaxAmount":"12",
            "invoiceLineTotalAmount":"135"
        },
        {
            "invoiceLineNo":"KB123456-2",
            "invoiceLineDesc":"Des124",
            "invoiceQty":"4",
            "invoicePpu":"0.17",
            "invoiceGstCode":"HSN1235",
            "invoiceGstPercentage":"18%",
            "invoiceLineAmount":"126",
            "invoiceLineTaxAmount":"14",
            "invoiceLineTotalAmount":"140"

        }
        ]

    }
}
```

`invoiceLineItems` can house up to 15 objects.

Here are my Entities Invoice and InvoiceLineItems

Invoice.Java

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long invoiceId;
    private String invoiceNumber;
    private long custId;
    private long pricingId;
    private long empId;
    private String gstCode;
    private String invoiceSubTotal;
    private String invoiceGst;
    private String invoiceGstAmount;
    private String invoiceTotal;

    @Transient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="invoice")
    private List<InvoiceLineItems> invoiceLineItems;
}
```

InvoiceLineItems.Java

```
@Entity
public class InvoiceLineItems {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long invoiceLineId;
    private String invoiceNumber;
    private String invoiceLineNo;
    private String invoiceLineDesc;
    private String invoiceQty;
    private String invoicePpu;
    private String invoiceGstCode;
    private String invoiceGstPercentage;
    private String invoiceLineAmount;
    private String invoiceLineTaxAmount;
    private String invoiceLineTotalAmount;

    @ManyToOne
    private Invoice invoice;
}
```

Here is my REST Controller

```
@RestController
public class InvoiceResourceController {

    @Autowired
    InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;
    InvoiceLineRepository invoiceLineRepository;

    @PostMapping("/invoice")
    public ResponseEntity<Invoice> createInvoice(@RequestBody Invoice invoice) {

        List<InvoiceLineItems> invoiceLineItemsList = invoice.getInvoiceLineItems();




        Invoice savedInvoice = invoiceRepository.save(invoice);

    /*  for (int i = 0; i < invoiceLineItemsList.size(); i++) {
            InvoiceLineItems invLn = new InvoiceLineItems();
            invLn = invoiceLineItemsList.get(i);

            invoiceLineRepository.save(invLn);

        } */



        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedInvoice.getInvoiceNumber()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }

}
```

Now, I have two tables Invoice and Invoice_Line_Items created by Spring Boot. I am able to persist the `Invoice` Entity to the `Invoice` table, but I'm struggling to get the `InvoiceLineItems` Array Object from request and persisting to `Invoice_Line_Items` table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `invoiceLineItemsList.foreach(i -> i.setInvoice(savedInvoice)); invoiceLineRepository.saveAll(invoiceLineItemsList);`

Comment: This didnt work. Tried already.

Comment: `
    @Transient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="invoice")
    private List<InvoiceLineItems> invoiceLineItems;
`
Try removing `@Transient`.
Properties marked as `@Transient` are not persisted

If it doen't work, try adding `cascade` to `invoiceLineItem` in `Invoice`

Comment: Nope! Didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "invoiceNumber")
private List<InvoiceLineItems> invoiceLineItems;
```